# How to block mailto opening email client from inside iframe in Electron webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, electron, mailto

I have a fullscreen, kiosk Electron webapp with an `iframe` of an online website in it. I can use the `sandbox` attribute of the `iframe` to block new windows and popups opening from links, but the `mailto:` links open the system default mail client and make the user leave the Electron app. Is there any way to block/intercept these links? I have no access to the contents of the frames. I've already tried the `will-navigate` event for the window, but that doesn't fire on clicking inside the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an event that does the same thing as `will-navigate` but handling links inside sub-frames of the pages, such as iframes: `will-frame-navigate`. This fixed my issue:

```
win.webContents.on( 'will-frame-navigate', ( event, url ) => {
    if ( url.startsWith( 'mailto:' ) )
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```